# override property on inherited object

Tags: .net, vb.net, oop

Can anybody please tell me the best way to customise a business object that is from a suit of core business objects (an existing framework) in the following way:

Say our object is Employee, which inherits from Person.
Person has a collection of objects, Phone Number (specified by underlying framework)
I want to redefine this object, specifying new fields, so I create object NewPhoneNumber, which inherits from PhoneNumber.

How do I make Employee use NewPhoneNumber without changing the underlying framework?

A) copy the code base, make the changes I want in my code to reflect this (ie. this is no longer utilising the underlying code base, but replicating it almost).  Ie. Create the Employee object as an almost identical object as Person but with changes?
B) Create a new collection property on the Employee object exposing a collection of NewPhoneNumber, which makes a strange object definition.

A would seem the only real solution, yet strangely does not seem very OO.

I specifically don't want to change the code-base, I'd simply like to inherit and extend the definition.  The underlying object would still be Person with PhoneNumbers, which is only extended by Employee and NewPhoneNumber.

I am using .Net (VB specifically)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't change that *underlying framework*, you're constrained to design your derived classes and set them to the existing properties.

For example (in C#, but still useful in VB.NET):

```
public class Person {}
public class EnhancedPerson : Person {}

public class Company 
{
     public Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

Imagine you don't own `Company` and `Person` source code. You can still set an `EnhancedPerson` to the `Person`-typed property on `Company`:

```
Company company = new Company();
// An upcast from EnhancedPerson to Person. No problem
// because an EnhancedPerson is a Person after all.
company.Person = new EnhancedPerson();
```

In order to achieve more typing at compile-time (i.e. let `Company.Person` property be typed as `Person` or a derived class of `Person`) [you need to use *generics*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w256ka79.aspx) and this would mean changing your base classes. For example, `Company` would look as follows:

```
public class Company<TPerson> where TPerson : Person
{
    public TPerson Person { get; set; }
}
```

...and use it:

```
Company<EnhancedPerson> company = new Company<EnhancedPerson>();
```

But you said you don't want to change your code base. Who knows if *generics* is a good reason to think about a refactoring to your solution. For me, a .NET source code without generics in 2015 is a good reason to rethink your scenario.